# C# can you place a timercallback inside of a webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to think of the best way to do retry logic while using a webservice to upload XML to a DataSource.  I was curious is it possible (or is there a better way) to use a timercallback inside of a webservice?

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: I don't think it's the responsibility of the webservice to do the retry, but it's the caller who should respond to this possible situation. Can you give some more insights on what is calling this webservice?

Comment: Basically what happens is that we insert a row into the database, and then after the insert a stored procedure is fired which then calls the webservice to insert the record in a third party system.  If it fails we do not want to loose the record, but retry to send the record over.

Comment: I think that's the logic within the webservice? I was more looking for who is calling the webservice, is that a windows service/ application, website or anything else?

Comment: Sorry just edited that, it gets called out of the database from a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I think the simplest solution will be to create another table, or update the existing table with an extra field, where you can mark if the record is succesfully send to the webservice and received.

Than instead of using the insert trigger, i would create a SQL job, which you can schedule to check for records that need to be sent by the webservice. You can reference to your stored procedure and use a transaction (if you are not already using it) and if the transaction succeeds update the record in your database for succesfull completion.